# ExtJs Drag drop tree, get drop Position

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have drag drop tree

and this is the viewConfig property

```
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
        appendOnly: true
    },
    listeners: {
        beforedrop: function (node,data,overModel,dropPosition,dropFunction,options){console.log(overModel)}
    }

},
```

I have two tree grid, what i want to get dropTarget position. Eg. Before node 3, after node 5...just like that

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably very old already. "overModel" is what you are interested in.